# suggest a query to in sql to find the unused tables

Tags: sql-server

SNAHi

anyone please suggest a query in sql to find the unused tables.

I have a legacy application migrated to .net from coldfusion.But lots of tables are unused now

What is the best way to find all the unused objects from database. (sql 2005)

thanks
SNA

Comment: Is legendary a typo? Did you mean "legacy" application...

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server, the acutal table data **IS** the clustered index. Using this query on the Dynamic Management Views (DMV) in SQL Server 2005 and up, you can find unused indices - if you find any clustered index (index_id=1) being unused over an extended period of time, the table is not being used anymore:

```
DECLARE  @dbid INT
SELECT @dbid = DB_ID(DB_NAME())

SELECT   
    OBJECTNAME = OBJECT_NAME(I.OBJECT_ID),
    INDEXNAME = I.NAME,
    I.INDEX_ID
FROM     
    SYS.INDEXES I
JOIN 
    SYS.OBJECTS O ON I.OBJECT_ID = O.OBJECT_ID
WHERE    
    OBJECTPROPERTY(O.OBJECT_ID, 'IsUserTable') = 1
    AND I.INDEX_ID NOT IN 
        (SELECT S.INDEX_ID
        FROM SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_USAGE_STATS S
        WHERE S.OBJECT_ID = I.OBJECT_ID
              AND I.INDEX_ID = S.INDEX_ID
              AND DATABASE_ID = @dbid)
ORDER BY 
    OBJECTNAME,
    I.INDEX_ID,
    INDEXNAME ASC
```

Another option would be to temporarily rename a table if you suspect it's not being used, and then see if your app(s) still work as expected. If they do for e.g. 30 days or so, then you're pretty sure you don't need that table anymore.

Marc

Comment: willthis cover bjects used by store procedures ,functions etc;

Answer (score 1):

-- Query to find the tables not used by any stored procedure, function nor view
-- Using SQL 2005 system tables, all programatical objects for dependencies, and one&only query:

```
select tables.name, progr.name
from sys.objects tables (nolock) 
    left join sys.syscomments comm (nolock) on comm.text like '%' + tables.name +'%'
    left join sys.objects progr (nolock) on progr.object_id = comm.id and progr.type in ('P', 'FN', 'TR', 'V' )
where tables.type = 'U'
    and comm.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query i have written to find the tables not used by any store procedures..
......................................................................................

```
Declare @tablename nvarchar(40)
Declare tablecursor cursor for
    Select name from sysobjects where xtype = 'U'
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
declare @rowCount int
DECLARE @searchstring varchar(50)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

create table #temp
(
    UnusedTables nvarchar(40)
)

open tablecursor
fetch next from tablecursor into @tablename
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin               
    set @searchstring='p'
    SET @sqlCommand = N'SELECT @rows = count(o.name) from sysobjects o , 
    syscomments c where o.type='+char(39)+@searchstring + char(39)+' and 
    o.id=c.id and c.text like '+ char(39)+'%' +  @tablename +'%'+char(39);
    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@rows int OUTPUT';              

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, @ParmDefinition,@rows=@rowCount OUTPUT;

    if @rowCount = 0 
    begin
        insert into #temp values (@tablename)                     
    end

    fetch next from tablecursor into @tablename
end

close tablecursor
deallocate tablecursor
select UnusedTables from #temp
drop table #temp
```

thanks 
SA

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
DECLARE @TableNameTemp TABLE
  (
     id        INT IDENTITY (1, 1),
     tablename VARCHAR(1000)
  )
INSERT INTO @TableNameTemp
SELECT table_name
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER  BY table_name
DECLARE @CursorTestID INT = 1;
DECLARE @TotalCount INT = (SELECT Count(1)
   FROM   @TableNameTemp)
DECLARE @FinalResult TABLE
  (
     unsedtables VARCHAR(max)
  )
DECLARE @TemExecInsert TABLE
  (
     testvalue VARCHAR(max),
     type      VARCHAR(max)
  )
DECLARE @TableaName VARCHAR(max) = ''
WHILE @CursorTestID <= @TotalCount
  BEGIN
      DELETE FROM @TemExecInsert
      SET @TableaName = (SELECT tablename
                         FROM   @TableNameTemp
                         WHERE  id = @CursorTestID)
      INSERT INTO @TemExecInsert
      EXEC Sp_depends
        @objname = @TableaName
      SET @CursorTestID = @CursorTestID + 1
      IF ( (SELECT Count(1)
            FROM   @TemExecInsert) = 0 )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @FinalResult
            VALUES      (@TableaName)
        END
  END
SELECT *
FROM   @FinalResult
```

PS: Sorry, I am not certain how to bring the answer in shape. Hope this helps